# Как использовать параметры запроса?

Tags: python, django

Пишу приложение на Django. Есть такой запрос, например, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/8/`. Вот функция в **views.py**:

```py
def product_detail_index(request, id):
    return render(f'{request}/{id}', 'storage_point/status.html')
```

А вот код в **urls.py**:

```py
path('status.html/<int:id>/', views.product_detail_index)
```

Но выдает ошибку `404`, не может найти файл. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить.

Comment: Что-то у вас чушь какая-то написана. Во-первых, функция `render` в первом аргументе принимает объект request, а вы с какого-то перепуга запихнули туда строку. Во-вторых, показанный вами «код в url» не содержит никакого `product/`, а значит вполне логично, что ссылка `/product/8/` просто обязана выдавать ошибку 404 из-за отсутствия соответствующего маршрута в «коде в url»